# Why can I not pass values initialized in the constructor of my Code Igniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this controller in Code Igniter application. A value is initialized in the constructor.

```
class Cat extends CI_Controller {
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['sound'] = "meow";
    }                                 
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('myCatPage', $data); 
    }
}
```

The view "views/myCatPage.php" looks like this. It is simple.

```
<?= $sound ?>
```

Why does PHP note this error?

```
Message: Undefined variable: sound
```

I thought I sent this variable as a key in the array (`$data`) I sent into the view.
I have tried

```
$this->load->view('myCatPage', $this->data);
```

but that strangely fails too.

Comment: i'm not familiar with code igniter, but if $data is an associative array, would it need to be $data['sound']

Comment: @thescientist no it wouldn't. In CI, if `$data ['sound'] == 'meow'` in the controller means that `$sound == 'meow'` in the view

Comment: @thescientist, it's because `CI` extracts the array in the view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class Cat extends CI_Controller {
    var $data = array();
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['sound'] = "meow";
    }                                 
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('myCatPage', $this->data); 
    }
}
```